# Error in consulting All Websites in the Matomo [fechada]

Tags: matomo

I’m configure matomo server in AWS cloud with server of 4 nucleos and 16GB RAM. The database is in RDS da AWS. But when I go to all websites and select data renge, I get the folloing error message: “Oops… there was a problem during the request.” I set all recommended settings. The other options in AllWebsites return the reports.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like there is an error on the Matomo servers and that the PHP process is failing with an error.

-> Can you please get the team to check your Web server error.log for the actual error message(s) logged by the server?

Once we see the error messages we will likely be able to understand where the problem is, and help provide a solution.